# Equivalent of suffix -able

Tags: суффиксы

I saw quite a few present passive participles (ending in **-емый**, **-имый**) which are translated into English with the suffix *-able*, *-ible*.

Like `невидимый - invisible`, `непредсказуемый - unpredictable`.

Naturally, not all present passive participles are translated into *-able*, but does the inverse occur? I mean, can I take any English word ending in *-able*, such as *replaceable*, and convey the same meaning in Russian by attaching the suffix *-емый/-имый*? Does `знаменимый` exist with the meaning *"replaceable"*?

Comment: Заменимый exists, but we can't say for sure about all participles,  but the majority exists. Though suffixes can be different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think anyone has ever analysed correspondence or did a statistical analysis of *translateability* between the respective English adjectives and Russian present passive participles, but let's conduct an exercise

[the list source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/spelling/words-ending-in-able-or-ible)

> likeable - привлекательный, располагающий к себе
>   peaceable - миролюбивый
>   debatable - спорный
>   pleasurable - приятный, доставляющий удовольствие
>   adaptable - **легкоадаптируемый, легкоприспосабливаемый**
>   inimitable - **неподражаемый, неповторимый**
>   capable - способный
>   adorable - милый, **обожаемый**
>   desirable - желательный
>   justifiable - оправданный
>   preferable - предпочтительный
>   disposable - одноразовый, **используемый однократно, выбрасываемый**
>   knowledgeable - осведомлённый, знающий
>   amiable - дружелюбный
>   durable - стойкий, устойчивый, долговечный
>   laughable - смехотворный
>   fashionable - модный
>   reliable - надёжный
>   excitable - **легковозбудимый**
>   lovable - вызывающий симпатию, заслуживающий любви
>   believable - вероятный, заслуживающий доверия, вызывающий доверие
>   excusable - простительный
>   manageable - поддающийся управлению, **управляемый**
>   serviceable - пригодный к использованию
>   measurable - **измеримый, измеряемый**
>   sizeable - внушительный
>   noticeable - заметный
>   suitable - подходящий, пригодный
>   changeable - переменчивый, меняющийся, **изменяемый**
>   tolerable - **терпимый**, сносный
>   objectionable - предосудительный, **недопустимый**
>   comfortable - удобный, комфортабельный, комфортный
>   payable - подлежащий уплате/оплате, **оплачиваемый, взимаемый**
>   impressionable - впечатлительный
>   conceivable - **вообразимый, постижимый**
>   operable - работоспособный, исправный
>   transferable - переносной, переводной, **переводимый, передаваемый**

So you can draw your conclusions. Although some do invite translation with present passive participle or could in certain contexts be translated with those, overall the most obvious equivalent would be a simple adjective. Sometimes obstacle could come from the type of a Russian verb which doesn't provide for formation of passive participles like in the case of `laughable` and Russian reflexive `смеяться`.

I think the chances are higher for adjectives formed out of actual verbs, because not all -able/ible adjectives have verb counterparts. And also good chances of being translated with Russian present passive participle have English past participles used in present tense.

Comment: I don't think `durable` should be in this list as it's not verb-derived. Good answer though.

Comment: @Sergey Slepov appreciate it, in fact not all of them are verb based, some  are derived also from nouns like *objectionable*

Comment: Well, from your aforementioned examples, it seems to me that the *-able* suffix may be equivalent to the present passive participle, whenever *-able* means ´"possible to be achieved"´. You quoted a few examples in which the -able suffix just converts a noun into an adjective (like *comfort - comfortable*, *knowledgeable*, *fashionable*). But yes, I noticed that a few translations take the past passive participle rather than the present passive.

Comment: @swrutra yes, i don't disagree with your observation, one limitation though is that Russian participle may not be suitable for all contexts in which the English adjective is used

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Баян Купи-ка's answer, some people use the English suffix -able directly with Russian verbs thus producing:

- [чита́бельный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) 'easy to read / worth reading'
- [игра́бельный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) 'easy to play / worth playing'
- [смотри́бельный](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) 'easy to watch', etc

It's a relatively new trend and it's far from being standard Russian. It's more of a slang. It can sound cool when used right. Sort of like my five year old son awarding a new cartoon with a reserved 'Umm, not bad'.

Comment: *читабельный* appears in print since 1930s, so it is not that new, but indeed it sounds marked, as almost any combination of a Slavic route with a Latin suffix.